# Oracle aggregate function to return a random value for a group?

Tags: oracle, plsql, random, aggregate

The standard SQL aggregate function `max()` will return the highest value in a group; `min()` will return the lowest.

Is there an aggregate function in Oracle to return a random value from a group? Or some technique to achieve this?

E.g., given the table `foo`:

```
group_id value
1        1
1        5
1        9
2        2
2        4
2        8
```

The SQL query

```
select group_id, max(value), min(value), some_aggregate_random_func(value)
from foo
group by group_id;
```

might produce:

```
group_id  max(value), min(value), some_aggregate_random_func(value)
1        9            1           1
2        8            2           4
```

with, obviously, the last column being any random value *in that group*.

Comment: Gary, because I want dome random value in between [min,max], not the median.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try something like the following

```
select deptno,max(sal),min(sal),max(rand_sal) 
from(
select deptno,sal,first_value(sal) 
     over(partition by deptno order by dbms_random.value) rand_sal
from emp)
group by deptno
/
```

The idea is to sort the values within group in random order and pick the first.I can think of other ways but none so efficient.

Comment: Wow, I'd have thought "order by dbms_random.value" would be interpreted as a column number. But testing shows this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might prepend a random string to the column you want to extract the random element from, and then select the min() element of the column and take out the prepended string.

```
select group_id, max(value), min(value), substr(min(random_value),11)
from (select dbms_random.string('A', 10)||value random_value,foo.* from foo)
```

In this way you cand avoid using the aggregate function and specifying twice the group by, which might be useful in a scenario where your query is very complicated / or you are just exploring the data and are entering manually queries with a  lengthy and changing list of group by columns.