# SQL aggregate function for any non-specific value from a group

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there an agregate function that returns any value from a group.  I could use `MIN` or `MAX`, but would rather avoid the overhead if possible given it's a text field.

My situation is an error log summary.  The errors are grouped by the type of error and an example of the error text is displayed for each group.  It doesn't matter which error message is used as the example.

```
SELECT
    ref_code,
    log_type,
    error_number,
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    MIN(data) AS example
FROM data
GROUP BY
    ref_code,
    log_type,
    error_number
```

What can I replace `MIN(data)` with to not have to compare 100,000s of varchar(2000) values?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066700/oracle-aggregate-function-to-return-a-random-value-for-a-group

Comment: The `min()` and `max()` are going to have minimal overhead.  Just reading in the strings will incur much more overhead than the comparison logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, good to know.  However, if the function I want exists, it will negate the need to read any more than one line of text per group, which is far less than one per record.

Comment: @DWright, thank you for introducing me to the `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` clauses.  I can't work out how to use them to return one arbitrary record from a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the proposed answers, it appears that `MIN(data)` (or `MAX(data)`) is the fastest way to achieve what I want.  I'm trying to over-optimise unnecessarily.

I'll try out any other answers that come up while I have access to this database, but in the mean time, this comes out on top.

Thank you for everyone's effort!

Answer (score 4):

you can use MIN coupled with KEEP, like this:

```
MIN(data) keep (dense_rank first order by rowid) AS EXAMPLE
```

The idea behind this is that the database engine will be sorting data over ROWID instead of the VARCHAR(2000) values, which theoretically should be faster. You can replace ROWID with the primary key value, and check if it's faster

Comment: Thanks!  While that works as pescribed, unfortunately it runs about 20% slower than a simple `MIN(data)` statement.  At least this supports the theory that I'm over-optimising.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you asked about OVER PARTITION AND ORDER BY, below is a version that does your GROUP BY, but then also uses ROW_NUMBER() with OVER and PARTITION AND ORDER BY, to number the first `ref_code, log_type, error_num` combination it comes across as row number 1 (with whatever data column is there at 1). Then it renumbers, starting at 1, at the next distinct `ref_code, log_type, error_num` combination it finds (with whatever data column that happens to be there).  So you can then simply pull the data field at row number 1 as a representative data field for a given `ref_code, log_type, error_num`.

It's still lacking something.  It would be more elegant if I didn't have the double pass (once for aggregation and once for row_number()); however, it might perform very well none-the-less.  I'll have to think about it some more to see if I can eliminate the double pass.

But it avoids any comparison of the large data field.  And it is represents a way to do what you asked: to pull 1 representative sample from the data field in correlation with the aggregated fields.

```
SELECT
    t.ref_code,
    t.log_type,
    t.error_number,
    t.count,
    d.data
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ref_code,
        log_type,
        error_number,
        COUNT(*) as count
    FROM data
    GROUP BY
        ref_code,
        log_type,
        error_number
) t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        ref_code,
        log_type,
        error_number,
        data,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY
                ref_code,
                log_type,
                error_number
            ORDER BY
                ref_code,
                log_type,
                error_number
        ) as row_number
    FROM data
) d on
    d.ref_code = t.ref_code and
    d.log_type = t.log_type and
    d.error_number = t.error_number and
    row_number = 1
```

Final caveat:  I don't have Oracle to try this on. But I did put it together from reading Oracle documentation.

---

I added the below after I thought further how to elminate the GROUP BY, which I only had in there for COUNT(*).  Don't know if it's any faster though.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ref_code,
        log_type,
        error_number,
        data,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY
                ref_code,
                log_type,
                error_number
            ORDER BY
                ref_code,
                log_type,
                error_number
        ) as row_number,
        COUNT(*) OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY
                ref_code,
                log_type,
                error_number
            ORDER BY
                ref_code,
                log_type,
                error_number
        ) as count 

    FROM data
) t
WHERE row_number = 1
```

Comment: Very thought provoking, but unfortunately this one's about 130% slower.  All the same, I'm learning a lot about more advanced SQL techniques which never goes astray.

Comment: Cool, thanks for giving it a try and good to know about the performance degradation.

Comment: Incidentally, the only reason I had to keep the GROUP BY in there was because I couldn't figure out how to have a count otherwise.  With no need for a count, I could have just gotten all the info from `SELECT  
        ref_code,  
        log_type,  
        error_number,  
        data,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY
                ref_code,
                log_type,
                error_number
            ORDER BY
                ref_code,
                log_type,
                error_number
        ) as row_number
    FROM data WHERE row_number = 1`

Comment: You can actually do a `COUNT(*) OVER` . . ., but I'd have had to do do such OVERs, one for the `COUNT(*)` and one for the `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: In any case, I added that as an the result of those last thoughts (comment) as alternative to my answer, below the original. I'd be curious how the performance is?

Comment: Nope, that one's woefully slow.  900% slower.

Comment: Hahaha.  Oh well.  I did't think it would be better, just not so much worse. It has to partition twice, so the problem of a double pass hasn't been really solved.