# How get specific rows in grouped result

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i need to group some data but because there are 4 store images , sql query return 4 result for every store. How can i get only one for a store by using sql query ?

```
select s.name,si.SHOP_IMG_PATH,count(*) amount  from stab t 
inner join shop s on (s.shop_id = t.shop_id) 
inner join SHOP_IMG si on (s.shop_id= si.SHOP_ID) 
where t.acct_id = 111 and t.CR_DATE >= sysDate - 1
group by s.name,si.SHOP_IMG_PATH 
order by 3 desc,1 asc
```

**As you see below image there a re 4 images so query can give random image**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
group by s.name, si.SHOP_IMG_PATH
```

You're telling it to differentiate them according to `SHOP_IMG_PATH`. Hence, it shows 4 results, one for each of those.

You'll have to drop `SHOP_IMG_PATH` from the `select` clause, if you won't let it use it.

## Edit

Got your comment. What you're looking for is **random aggregation**. This is achieved diferently on different SQL engines. Google around for the one you're using.

If it's Oracle, as indicated by the question tag, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066700/oracle-aggregate-function-to-return-a-random-value-for-a-group)

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by s.name, si.SHOP_IMG_PATH it will consider all possible combination of s.name, si.SHOP_IMG_PATH as separate you need to keep group by only s.name

Try this

```
SELECT a.NAME, a.PATH, a.AMOUNT
FROM (select 
     s.name AS 'NAME', si.SHOP_IMG_PATH AS 'PATH', count(*) AS 'AMOUNT',
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.name
                             ORDER BY type si.SHOP_IMG_PATH) AS rk 
from 
     stab t 
inner join shop s on (s.shop_id = t.shop_id) 
inner join SHOP_IMG si on (s.shop_id= si.SHOP_ID) 
where t.acct_id = 111 and t.CR_DATE >= sysDate - 1
group by s.name
order by 3 desc,1 asc) a
WHERE a.rk = 1;
```

Alternative
You will get result but this is just a workaround and easy alternative to your problem but not a good one.

```
select s.name AS 'NAME', min(si.SHOP_IMG_PATH) AS 'PATH', count(*) AS 'AMOUNT',
from 
     stab t 
inner join shop s on (s.shop_id = t.shop_id) 
inner join SHOP_IMG si on (s.shop_id= si.SHOP_ID) 
where t.acct_id = 111 and t.CR_DATE >= sysDate - 1
group by s.name
order by 3 desc,1 asc
```

This second query will return result as per your need

Comment: Hi, it says  in this line  "ORDER BY type si.SHOP_IMG_PATH) AS rk  " missing right parenthesis but i didnt see where is the missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using below query,

```
select s.name,t.shop_id,(select min(SHOP_IMG_PATH) from SHOP_IMG si where shop_id =t.shop_id),count(*) amount  from stab t 
inner join shop s on (s.shop_id = t.shop_id) 
where t.acct_id = 111 and t.CR_DATE >= sysDate - 1
group by s.name,t.shop_id
order by 4 desc,1 asc
```